# Running pytest command outside of docker container failes because container stopped

Tags: python, docker, containers, pytest, selenium-grid

I use docker selenium grid and pytest to execute tests. What i now do is:

- Spin up selenium grid via a makerfile
- Spin up the docker container (with a volume pointing to my local pc for the tests). The container also runs the pytest command.

This all works good, except that i would rather split the second action and be able to run the test on an already running container. Preferred setup:

- Spin up selenium grid + docker container with pyton+pytest
- A command to run the tests (with the container as interpretor)

When i tried to do this, i faced the issue that the python+pytest container stops running when the commands are all done. There is no long living process.

```
Dockerfile
FROM python:3.9.0-alpine
RUN apk add tk

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN ls ..

CMD pytest --junitxml ../r/latest.xml
```

My docker-compose file looks like:

```
docker-compose.yml
version: "3.0"
services:

  pytest:
    container_name: pytest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./t:/t 
      - ./r:/r 
    working_dir: /t/

networks:
  default:
      name: my_local_network #same as selenium grid
```

It does not 'feel' good to have this pytest command in the container settings itself.

Answer (score 1):

### Container shutting down

That's because the `CMD pytest --junitxml ../r/latest.xml` line will execute once and when complete it will exit the container.

### To run a cmd on an existing container

You can run commands on an existing docker container using this command:

```
docker exec <container_name> python -m pytest
```

Where `<container_name>` would be `pytest` in your case, since that is what the container is called in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

See here for more info: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

---

### Using Make

If you want to extend this to a `makefile` command:

```
docker:
    docker-compose up -d

ci-tests: docker
    docker exec <container_name> python -m pytest
```

To both spin up AND run tests you can use:

```
make ci-tests
```

---

You could run selenium-grid in docker too if you wanted to make this solution completely portable: https://www.conductor.com/nightlight/running-selenium-grid-using-docker-compose/